# Prove $A>P^{T}B^{-1}P$ iff $B>PA^{-1}P^{T}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Suppose $A,B$ are $n\times n$ positive definite real symmetric matrices,P is an $n\times n$ real matrix, prove that 
>   $A>P^{T}B^{-1}P$ iff $B>PA^{-1}P^{T}$.

By using the orthogonal diagonalization, I can prove this when $P$ is nonsingular.  I have tried Polar decomposition, but I didn't know how to deal with $P$, since it can be singular.